# WMS in Google Chrome (ArcGIS API JavaScript) not working

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms, chrome

I am doing a small web with WMS, but I have a problem with Google Chrome (and IE... but with this one I don't mind). Down of this lines there is two website:

Galicia: This one contains WMS from Galicia (north of Spain) and it *loads correctly* on Firefox and Chrome. Right

http://signo-geo.com/alejandrowms/mapacorrecto2.html

Andalucia (south of Spain): In this second App, the WMS on Chrome is not loading but in Firefox it works fine.

http://signo-geo.com/alejandrowms/mapaprueba2.html

I was looking for information about that and only find this thread.

```
http:// forums.arcgis.com/threads/98149-Chrome-WMS-and-content-type-application-vnd.ogc.wms_xml-fails..
```

Here is an Image which shows the problem:
[image]

Why is the WMS not appearing in the second App, even though the code is similar to the first one? And why does this problem occur only in Google Chrome and not Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: I upload an image to help the explanation https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfis5hhkoeb6axg/Differences.jpg .  upside is Galicia WMS and downside is Andalucia WMS. (Right Firefox / left Google Chrome)

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. What is the question? Please click edit below your question to add something with a question mark!

Comment: As I understand this problem is due to Chrome having a problem with the response header `Content-Type:application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml` If you want a quick solution, I'll change the proxy.php that you to return a Header of `Content-Type:text/xml` in this kind of situation. it's dirty and 'Hacky' but will get the job done.

Comment: Thanks Devdatta, I used this  'header("Content-Type:text/xml");' in proxy.php and doesn't work :(. I send to technical support this problem, and they are working in this... if someone has any solution, tell me please!... If technical fix that I'll post here the final solution. Thanks people!